# How to Upgrade Flutter without the fast-forwarding error?

Tags: flutter

I am not able to upgrade flutter. Whenever I give the command,

```
C:\src\flutter\bin>flutter upgrade
```

I am getting an error

```
Upgrading Flutter from C:\src\flutter...
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

I don't see any error when I give the command

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.17.0-3.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

except no devices connected.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

change to beta channel with command: flutter channel beta
the run flutter upgrade